# Linq to XML - Query returns nothing

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have a XML file on which when I run a LINQ query returns nothing in the for loop.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReadOrderResponseType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Status xmlns="urn:mysite:apis">Success</Status>
 <TimeStamp xmlns="urn:mysite:apis">2010-07-25T15:26:49.1150235Z</TimeStamp>
 <StoreUrl xmlns="urn:mysite:apis">http://XYZ.COM</StoreUrl>
 <PageResponse xmlns="urn:mysite:apis">
  <Page>1</Page>
  <Size>10</Size>
  <TotalSize>18033</TotalSize>
  <HasMore>true</HasMore>
 </PageResponse>
 <OrderList OrderId="20147184" OrderNumber="20100560" xmlns="urn:mysite:apis">
  <Archived>false</Archived>
  <CreateDate>2010-07-25T01:37:04.067Z</CreateDate>
</OrderList>
</ReadOrderResponseType>
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(myOrders.xml)
                Dim query = From O In document.Root.Elements("OrderList") _
                 Select New With _
                 { _
                    .Archived= O.Element("Archived").Value, _
                    .Status = O.Element("CreateDate").Value _
                 }

                For Each Order In query
                    Console.WriteLine(Order.Archived)
                    Console.ReadLine()
                Next
```

It does not even go inside the for loop.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're going to have to edit your post and escape your XML so the rest of us can see it.  My first guess is that your XML has a namespace that you neglected, but again - without a well formatted post you won't get much help.

Answer (score 1):

You need a namespace qualifier. Try something like:

```
    Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml")
    Dim apins As XNamespace = "urn:mysite:apis"
    Dim query = From O In document.Root.Elements(apins + "OrderList") _
     Select New With _
     { _
        .Archived = O.Element(apins + "Archived").Value, _
        .Status = O.Element(apins + "CreateDate").Value _
     }

    For Each Order In query
        Console.WriteLine(Order.Archived)
        Console.ReadLine()
    Next
```